# How to track people across multiple cameras?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

This is the setup: A fairly large room with 4 fish-eye cameras mounted on the ceiling. There are no blind spots. Each camera coverage overlaps a little with the other.

The idea is to track people across these cameras. As of now a blob extracting algorithm is in place, which detects people as blobs. It's a fairly decently working algorithm which detects individual people pretty good. Am using the OpenCV API for all of this.

What I mean by track people is that - Say, camera 1 identifies two people, say Person A and Person B. Now, as these two people move from the coverage of camera 1 into the overlapping area of coverage of cam1 and cam2 and into the area where only cam2 covers, cam2 should be able to identify them as the same people A and B cam1 identified them as.

This is what I thought I'd do -
1) The camera renders the image at 15fps and I think the dimensions of the frames are of 1920x1920.

2) Identify blobs individually in each camera and give each blob an unique label.

3) Now as for the overlaps - Compute an affine transformation matrix which maps pixels on one camera's frame onto another camera's frame - this needn't be done for every frame - this can be done before the whole process starts, as a pre-processing step. So in real time, whenever I detect a blob which is in the overlapping area, all I have to do is apply the transformation matrix to the pixels in cam1 and see if there is a corresponding blob in cam2 and give them the same label.

So, Questions :

1) Would this system give me a badly-working system which tracks people decently ?

2) So, for the affine transform, do I have to convert the fish-eye to rectilinear image ? (My answer is yes, but am not too sure)
Please feel free to point out possible errors and why certain things might not work in the process I've described. Also alternate suggestions are welcome! TIA

Comment: I might be missing something but could you implement a system where: when blobA leaves a certain part of cameraA's view, and an unknown blob enters on a certain part of another camera, it is definitely blobA?

Answer (score 0):

1- blob extraction is not enough to track a specific object, for people case I suggest [HoG](http://lear.inrialpes.fr/people/triggs/pubs/Dalal-cvpr05.pdf) - or at least background subtraction before blob extraction, since all of the cameras have still scenes.

2- opencv <=2.4.9 uses pinhole model for stereo vision. so, before any calibration with opencv methods your fisheye images must be [converted to](http://research.ijcaonline.org/volume51/number10/pxc3881483.pdf) rectilinear images first. You might try calibrating yourself using [other approaches](http://www.ee.oulu.fi/~jkannala/publications/tpami2006.pdf) too

release 3.0.0 will have support for [fisheye model](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#fisheye). It is on alpha stage, you can still download and give it a try.